# Cannot add an instance of my class to the list<my class>

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a Powershell script that declares a class and then tries to add an instance of this class to a list:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class BuildWarning
{
    public string Solution { get; private set; }
    public string Project { get; private set; }
    public string WarningMessage { get; private set; }
    public string WarningCode { get; private set; }
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
    private static readonly Regex warningMessageKeyRegex = new Regex(@"^(?<before>.*)\([0-9,]+\)(?<after>: warning .*)$");
    public BuildWarning(string solution, string project, string warningMessage, string warningCode)
    {
        Solution = solution;
        Project = project;
        WarningMessage = warningMessage;
        WarningCode = warningCode;
        var match = warningMessageKeyRegex.Match(WarningMessage);
        Key = Solution + "|" + Project + "|" + match.Groups["before"].Value + match.Groups["after"].Value;
    }
}
"@

[System.Collections.Generic.List``1[BuildWarning]] $warnings = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List``1[BuildWarning]"

[BuildWarning] $newWarning = New-Object BuildWarning("", "", "", "")

$warnings += $newWarning
```

At the last line I get an error:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type
"BuildWarning".
At C:\development\temp\BuildWarningReportGenerator.ps1:93 char:17
+                 $warnings += $newWarning
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is. The type checks show that types of both `$warnings` and `$newWarning` are correct. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jyao's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52123419/45375) provides an effective solution:

In order **to append elements to your `` [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BuildWarning]] `` instance, use its `.Add()` method, not PowerShell's `+=` operator.**

What PowerShell's `+=` operator *normally* does is to treat a collection-valued LHS as an *array* - irrespective of the specific LHS collection type - and "appends" to that array, i.e., it creates a (new) array containing all elements of the LHS collection followed by the RHS element(s).

In other words: **using `+=` *ignores the specific LHS collection type* and invariably assigns a (new) `[object[]]` array comprising the LHS collection's elements plus the RHS** element(s).

This behavior may be surprising, given that it's reasonable to expect the specific collection type of the LHS to be preserved - see [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5805).

In your specific case, **you're seeing a *bug* in Windows PowerShell as of v5.1**, which has been fixed in PowerShell *Core*:

The **problem arises if you try to *type-constrain* the list variable**, `$warnings` in your case. Type-constraining means placing a type (cast) before the LHS variable name, which locks the variable's type in, so that subsequent assignments must be of the same or a compatible type.

To provide a simple example:

```
$list = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[int]'
$list += 1  # OK - $list is not type-constrained
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Unconstrained `$list 'extended': $list"


# Type-constrained $list
[System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] $list = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[int]'
$list += 1  # !! BREAKS, due to the bug
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Type-constrained `$list 'extended': $list"
```

I encourage you to report this bug in the [Windows PowerShell UserVoice forum](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell).

Answer (score 6):

How about this way?

```
#do not use this way
#$warnings += $newWarning

#but use this instead
$warnings.Add($newWarning)
```

Comment: It does fix the error. Thank you. But can you explain the reason?